# Postgres syntax error near if

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have the following code, this is the shrunk version of the function for the trigger on the table i want to apply the trigger, the table actually has many fields:

```
Create OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRC_EPV_() 
RETURNS trigger AS $PRC_EPV_$

begin

  Declare BaseCount bigint default 0;
  Declare PeakCount bigint default 0;
  Declare BaseSUM DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;
  Declare PeakSum DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;

    IF new.epv_kw_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
         set BaseSum = BaseSum + new.EPV_KW_1;
         set BaseCount = BaseCount + 1;
    END if;

     IF  new.EPV_KW_38 IS NOT NULL Then
         set BaseSum = BaseSum + new.EPV_KW_38;
         set PeakSum = PeakSum + new.EPV_KW_38;
         set BaseCount = BaseCount + 1;
         set PeakCount = PeakCount + 1;
     END if;
     IF new.EPV_KW_91 IS NOT NULL Then
         set BaseSum = BaseSum + new.EPV_KW_91;
         set BaseCount = BaseCount + 1;
     END if;

     set new.EPV_Peak_Sum = PeakSum ;
     set new.EPV_Base_Sum = BaseSum ;

     IF PeakCount > 0 Then
      set new.EPV_Peak_AVE =  new.EPV_peak_Sum / PeakCount * 4;
     END if;

     IF BaseCount > 0 Then
     set new.EPV_Base_AVE =  new.EPV_base_Sum / BaseCount * 4;
     END if;

    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$PRC_EPV_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

pgAdmin SQL Editor tells me 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 11:  IF new.epv_kw_1 IS NOT NULL THEN

for the life of me I cant work out why I tried replacing the condition statement with 'true', '1', '-1', '1=1' all the time it gives me the same syntax error near IF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
RETURNS trigger AS $PRC_EPV_$

begin

  Declare BaseCount bigint default 0;
  Declare PeakCount bigint default 0;
  Declare BaseSUM DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;
  Declare PeakSum DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;

    IF new.epv_kw_1
```

into

```
RETURNS trigger AS $PRC_EPV_$
Declare 
  BaseCount bigint default 0;
  PeakCount bigint default 0;
  BaseSUM DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;
  PeakSum DOUBLE PRECISION default 0;
begin
    IF new.epv_kw_1
```

Comment: simple on in the end, sorry, seems im still hung over on the mySQL order of things :)

Comment: you are very welcome - I'm still adding NOLOGGING to the end sometimes :)